# asp.net Radar chart. Show lines instead of filled area

Tags: asp.net, charts, radar-chart

I am using the asp.net radar chart and I am trying to get it to show with just lines rather than filled area.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3ERq.png)  has an example of something similar to what I am looking for. The image on the left is the preview from VS of the current chart. The one on the right is what I want it to look like (just lines)

My html for my chart is as follows:

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Palette="Bright">
<Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="Radar">
    </asp:Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series2" ChartType="Radar">
    </asp:Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series3" ChartType="Radar">
    </asp:Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series4" ChartType="Radar">
    </asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="0">
        <AxisY>
            <MajorGrid LineColor="lightgray" />
        </AxisY>
    </asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
```

Is there a way to adapt this so it shows without the filled area or does the asp.net chart not have this option? I can't seem to find an option.

**UPDATE**

I have done much more searching and have found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456763.aspx), it talks about "RadarDrawingStyle" I am unsure as yet how to apply this to my html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have found I need to set it like this:

```
 Chart1.Series[0]["RadarDrawingStyle"] = "Line";
```

I was hoping to set it in the html but there doesn't seem a way